# Ajax callback: d3 outputs the same thing when different inputs are given

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js

I have a function called show_product_price to draw line based on input data (containing date and price).

When I did a test by manually generating 2 dataset, then call the function, everything works fine and 2 lines are drawn.

like this:

```
show_product_price(data1, "origin");
show_product_price(data2, "competitor");
```

But when I try to call the function using 2 ajax calls. Problem happens. The function does receive 2 different datasets, but the 2 lines drawn overlap each other. Basically the 2 lines use the same dataset, even though during the 2 ajax call, the function receive 2 daatset.

I am not sure why this is happening.

The ajax looks like:

```
//inside one function, ajax call to get one dataset, I checked show_product_price() receive it successfuly
$.ajax({
  url: 'xxx',
  success: function(data) {
      show_product_price(data, "origin");
  }
 });

//inside another function, get another dataset, also received successfuly
$.ajax({
  url: 'xxx',
  success: function(data) {
      show_product_price(data, "competitor");
  }
 });
```

The function is:

```
function show_product_price(input, who) {

    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input));
    // I did an alert() here, i amde sure the data passed in is different

    //#visualisation is a svg 
    var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
    WIDTH = 1000,
    HEIGHT = 500,
    MARGINS = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 50
    },

    //set up scale here
    xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right])
        .domain([new Date(data[0].date), 
            d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)]),

    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom])
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                return d.price;
              }) * 1.5]);

    if (who == "origin") {
      // Append axis and text, code works, omit here

    }

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) {
                  return xScale(parseDate(d.date));
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                  return yScale(d.price);
                })
                .interpolate("basis");

    var color = "green";

    if (who == "competitor") {
      color = "red";
    }

    // draw each data point as a circle 
    vis.selectAll("circle." + who)
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", who)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return xScale(parseDate(d.date));
         })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.price);
         })
        .attr("fill", color)
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) { return i * (3000 / (data.length - 1)); })
        .attr("r", 5);

    //draw lines connecting the circles
    vis.append('svg:path')
         .attr('d', lineGen(data))
         .attr('stroke', color)
         .attr("id", who)
         .attr('stroke-width', 2)
         .attr('fill', 'none');
}
```

Comment: this has to do with the 'D3 Update Pattern' here are some links to get you going: 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218,     
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221,     
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234,   
note the 'update()' function in the above links

Comment: hi, i read those examples, but i am still not sure how they can be applied to my case. I did use different class when append